# Refer to parent using MouseEnter() event? (or any other events)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a pictureBox, the MouseEnter() event performs as follows:

```
private void PictureBox_pictureBox_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox.Load("..\\Debug\\Images\\highlightbutton");
    pictureBox.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
}
```

I want to have multiple pictureBoxes, which all refer to the same function named PictureBox_pictureBox_MouseEnter() as shown above. Is it possible to refer to the pictureBox dependant on which one is clicked? Something like this:

```
    private void PictureBox_pictureBox_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Parent.Load("..\\Debug\\Images\\highlightbutton");
        Parent.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
    }
```

Comment: `(PictureBox)sender`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sender` parameter is [a reference to the control that raised the event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/event-handlers-overview-windows-forms):

```cs
private void PictureBox_pictureBox_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pictureBox = sender as PictureBox;
    pictureBox.Load("..\\Debug\\Images\\highlightbutton");
    pictureBox.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
}
```